# Swift: Calling completion handler methods within in a for loop

Tags: ios, swift

I want to understand the behavior of for loop that has completion handler methods inside it.

See the below example where I am trying to get the latitude/longitude coordinates of 2 addresses.

```
let addressArray = ["1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino", "809, Harvard Ave, Sunnyvale, CA - 94087"]
var coordinatesArray = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()

for i in 0 ..< addressArray.count {
    print(i)
    let address = addressArray[i]
    geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
        print("Address = \(address)");
        if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
            let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate
            self.coordinatesArray.append(coordinate!)
        }
    })
}

// Do something here after that that
```

The output is like this

```
0
1
Address = 1 Infinite Loop, Cupertino
```

I am wondering why is the other address not printed in the code. Is the second for loop not calling the geocodeAddressString method. Assume that the application execution is not over after the for loop ends and I do many other things.

Comment: is that really the output or did you type that out? shouldnt the last line look like `Address = something`

Comment: Code you posted not directly connected to output, please use copy paste from code and console; also you printing `address`, what is this?

Comment: Updated the code and output.

Comment: You should be aware of race conditions in this type of asynchronous looped requests. Eiko mentions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35850500/completion-handler-in-for-in-loop-swift)

Comment: This is what I wanted to know, the race condition behavior with asynchronous looped requests.

Answer (score 1):

## Explanation:

- There is for loop which runs N times (addressArray.count).
- During each iteration, Geo coding request is made.
- It takes some time to fetch the place marks.
- This is an asynchronous method, so it doesn't block the execution (meaning loop continues to run and doesn't wait till the geo request completes).
- When the geo coding request for a particular iteration is completed it's completion handler would be executed.

## Problem:

- Since the order of completion is not guaranteed, it is better to use a dictionary instead of an array.
- Don't use an array because the order of completion might not be sequential.
- For example the 1st request might complete after the 2nd request completes.

## Solution:

- For a given integer index, the `coordinates[index]` will correspond to `addressArray[index]`

## Code (with proposed fix):

```
class Test {
    
    let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

    //Better use a dictionary instead of an array
    var coordinates = [Int: CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
    
    func f1() {
        
        for i in 0 ..< addressArray.count {
            print(i)
            let address = addressArray[i]
            
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(address) {placemarks, error in
                print("Address = \(address)");
                if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                    let coordinate = placemark.location?.coordinate
                    
                    self.coordinates[i] = coordinate
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will use a dictionary. I mainly wanted to know the behavior of asynchronous looped requests.